# Maven: How to "best" use maven also for downloding "project related files" like configuration .xmls?

Tags: java, maven

I am new to maven and ran into the following question/problem:

Given Hibernate as example: When I use maven, I can easily mange dependencies by including Hibernate as a dependency. The jars are manged perfectly. But Hinbernate consits of quite a lot of other (config) files that are required to get it running (like hibernate.cfg.xml).

1.) Does Maven provide any solution to also download these files (so I can use them as a basis for my additions. It would not make sense writing these complexe xmls newly from the scratch). => For Example is there "goal/target" in maven that spits out these required "relataed config" files into a specifc directory?

2.) How do you handle this case? Although I use mave, does this meand that I neverless have to download the common zip/gz Project-Files that used to contain these files? (As i did it in the past)=>So maven only manages/solves a part of the "problems" that I have in this regard.

Update: The files I am talking about are normally files I need to edit quite often (configuration files). So they are mostly not provided as a static config file inside the jars.

UPDATE 2 => Real live example: I just started to write a POM for my project and googled the dependency-names, like "hibernate-core", "hibernate-validation", "rome" (RSS Lib), "tuckey" (Rewrite Filter) and included them in my POM. Now I have all the jars downloaded via maven (great!), but however I do not have any (sample/base) config files. The Web-app can not be run...
Formerly (when I did not use maven) I downloaded the official distribution zip/gz package and they contained everything: jars and sample config files. Ok its great that maven helps me with the jars, but in the end I do have to navigate to every project webpage and also download the zip/gz distribuation package (as I did before) to only get the sample config files to include them in my project and then make some smaller changes... (without hibernate.cfg.xml hibernate does not start and writing it from scratch is an absolute nightmare, the best solution is take their sample file and update some specific stuff...

Thank you very much for any advice.
Markus

Comment: I'm not sure in what sense you're asking the question. Hibernate configs, for example, are specific to your app--not to Hibernate. Including them in the Hibernate download wouldn't make sense. A Hibernate project *archetype* would include (probably) a configuration file. Are you really asking about archetypes?

Comment: Sorry I do not know the correct technical terms. I am talking about a "sample/default/base" (= archtetypes?) file that I use as the foundation to update them with my specific configuration. And the question is where do I get these files from (so that I do not have to write them from scratch on my own). I know it makes no sense that they are included in the JAR but the question is where do I have to download them. Are they provided as another maven POM? thanks!

Comment: @Dave, thanks! Was new to me: For all "Maven Archetypes": http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html

Answer (score 4):

Most people handle this by including files like this inside their jars and referencing them via classpath.

If this doesn't appeal to you, and you have a bunch of them, the Maven solution is (a) use the assembly plugin to combine them into a jar or zip or tar; and attach the resulting item as an artifact with a non-empty classifier, and (b) use the maven-dependency-plugin to download the artifact and unpack it under target/something.